# Alamofire 1.3 on iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, alamofire

It looks like authentication headers are not being set on iOS 9. We cannot update to Alamofire 2.0 because we havent migrated our code to Swift 2 yet. Has some else run into this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, because I put the headers via the session configuration manager like that:

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders?.updateValue("Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==", forKey: "Authorization")
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders?.updateValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forKey: "Content-Type")
```

It worked fine with iOS 8, but with iOS9 it does nothing. I didn't noticed that you also can set the headers directly when you make the request:

```
let headers = [
    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", headers: headers)
         .responseJSON { _, _, JSON, _ in
             println(JSON)
         }
```

Now it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
    let headers = [
            "Authorization": userData.userAPIKey!,
        ]
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers:headers).response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample code, i am also getting same issue previously. Now it is resolve.

```
// Step : 1  
    var manager = Manager.sharedInstance

 // Specifying the Headers we need
 manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
    "Content-Type": "application/graphql",
    "Accept": "application/json" //Optional
    ]

 // Step : 3 then call the Alamofire request method.

Alamofire.request(.GET, url2).responseJSON { request, response,  result in
 print(result.value)
 }
```

Try this or you can check the latest update from alamofire on xcode 7:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: @ swift BUTCHER... Did you check with Alamofire 1.3. If yes, then paste your code here..